# Embedded array schema type not respected on Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, schema, mongoose-schema

I have been struggling and reading for quiet some time already and cannot seem to find a logical explanation to my problem.

This is the code with my schemas declarations:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose;
var exports = module.exports = {};

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    email: String,
    password: String
});

var messageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    text: String,
    user: userSchema,
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

var roomSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    topic: String,
    users: [userSchema],
    messages: [messageSchema],
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});


var User = mongoose.model("user", userSchema);
var Message = mongoose.model("message", messageSchema);
var Room = mongoose.model("room", roomSchema);
exports.Users = User;
exports.Messages = Message;
exports.Rooms = Room;
```

And then I am just creating some dummy data:

```
var usersArr = [];
var userTemp = new User({
    username: "Spiderman",
    email: "spiderman@chat.com",
    password: "password"
});
userTemp.save(function (err, user) {
    if (err)return console.log(err)
    //console.log(user);
});
usersArr.push(userTemp);

//some more users....

//messagesArr
var messagesArr = [];
var msgTemp = new Message({
    text: "I think Magneto is getting too old",
    user: usersArr[19]
});
msgTemp.save(function (err, msg) {
    if (err)return console.log(err)
    //console.log(msg);
});
messagesArr.push(msgTemp);

//some more msgs......

var roomsArr = [];
var roomTemp = new Room({
    name: "Villains",
    topic: "Discussing newly spotted villains on our streets",
    users: usersArr,
    messages: messagesArr
});
roomTemp.save(function (err, room) {
    if (err)return console.log(err)
   // console.log(room);
});
roomsArr.push(roomTemp);

//some more rooms........
```

Everything is working beautifully except when I try to pass the `messagesArr` in

```
var roomTemp = new Room({
        name: "Villains",
        topic: "Discussing newly spotted villains on pur streets",
        users: usersArr,
        messages: messagesArr
    });
```

Then everything crashes with

> value.validate(fn, {__noPromise: true});
>             ^
>
> TypeError: value.validate is not a function

To me it looks very similar to what I am doing with the other schemas and I cannot figure out what is wrong with this one. Any help will be much appreciated! It seems like that I am really missing something :/

Answer (score 0):

```
   var roomsArr = []; var roomTemp = new Room();
    roomTemp.name = "Villains";
    roomTemp.topic = "Discussing newly spotted villains on our streets";
    roomTemp.users = usersArr;
    roomTemp.messages.push({msg:messagesArr}); // I did chenages here

roomTemp.save(function (err, room) {
    if (err)return console.log(err)    // console.log(room); }); roomsArr.push(roomTemp);

I have done changes in your roomTemp object and saving it, now its
should work
```

Answer (score 0):

Here lets have final working code...

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'); var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var exports = module.exports = {};

var userSchema = new Schema({
    username: String,
    email: String,
    password: String });

var messageSchema = new Schema({
    text: String,
    //user: userSchema,
    user:Object,
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now} });

var roomSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    topic: String,
    users:[userSchema],
    messages:[messageSchema],
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now} });

var User = mongoose.model("user", userSchema); 
var Message = mongoose.model("message", messageSchema); 
var Room = mongoose.model("room", roomSchema); 
exports.Users = User;
exports.Messages = Message; 
exports.Rooms = Room;




require("./config/monDB"); 
require('./SOFmodel'); 
var mongoose = require("mongoose"); 
var User = mongoose.model("user");
var Message = mongoose.model("message"); 
var Room = mongoose.model("room");

var usersArr = []; 
var userTemp = new User({
    username: "Spiderman",
    email: "spiderman@chat.com",
    password: "password" });
   userTemp.save(function (err, user) {
    if (err)return console.log(err)
    //console.log(user); }); 
  usersArr.push(userTemp);

console.log(usersArr[0]); //some more users....

//messagesArr 
 var messagesArr = []; 
 var msgTemp = new Message({
    text: "I think Magneto is getting too old",
    user: usersArr[0] });

msgTemp.save(function (err, msg) {
    if (err)return console.log(err)
    //console.log(msg); }); 
messagesArr.push(msgTemp);

//some more msgs......

console.log(messagesArr); 
var roomsArr = []; 
var roomTemp = new Room();

    roomTemp.name = "Villains";
    roomTemp.topic = "Discussing newly spotted villains on our streets";
    roomTemp.users = usersArr;
    roomTemp.messages.push({msg:messagesArr});

roomTemp.save(function (err, room) {
    if (err)return console.log(err)    // console.log(room); }); roomsArr.push(roomTemp);
```

Comment: It is indeed working when the user:userSchema is commented, but isn't it the point to declare a user in the message schema? What I did is to instead of declaring it as a schema, just to have a user object declared. And I still don't understand what exactly is the problem. Isn't it supposed to more convenient to declare the schemas?